# Packages with broken dependencies

Tags: linux-mint, package-management

I am unable to install any debian packages because gdebi complains about packages with broken dependencies. Then I ran pkexec synaptic and found the culprits. Packages libicu_dev, libicu60 and libicu60:386 have broken dependencies.

How can I fix it?

dpkg doesn't even recognize they are installed.

How to fix these broken dependencies? Any clues?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What Debian version are you using? What are the missing dependencies, is `libicu60` (for example) a Ubuntu version? Just because a package has a DEB suffix doesn't mean that it is suitable for Debian...

Comment: Only packages compatible with the unknown 'Linux Mint' can be installed with gdebi. ........ And 32bit packages may not be supported with the latest "Mint".